# Selecionar texto na frente do texto atual usando TextBox

Tags: c#, textbox

Preciso que quando uma pessoa digite uma palavra, vai preenchendo automaticamente na frente do TextBox.

Esse é o texto PADRÃO Por Exemplo:

- *sdfdsfasfColocar esse texto no TextBoxsdfdsassdf*

Quando eu preencher um pedaço do texto acima no TextBox,

- *Colo(...)*

O resultado final terá que ficar assim no mesmo TextBox que digito:

- [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O azul só poderá desaparecer quando a palavra não for igual ao padrão, ou for maior.

Montei um código para isso, mas na hora de digitar, o texto selecionado não acompanha a sequência de palavras do texto padrão.

```
  private void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        int first = this.textBox1.TextLength;
        string padrao = "asdfjdkjdfColocar esse texto no TextBoxqewprqewriworuoewi";
        string textIndex = padrao.Remove(0, padrao.IndexOf(this.textBox1.Text, 0) + this.textBox1.TextLength);            
        this.textBox1.Text = this.textBox1.Text.Insert(this.textBox1.Text.Length, textIndex);
        this.textBox1.Select(first, this.textBox1.Text.Length);
  }
```

O meu objetivo é apenas selecionar o texto padrão enquanto digito e colocar na frente do texto atual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A textbox tem um modo de auto complete, o que difere do que prentende é que apenas pega a string do inicio.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Append;
    this.textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;

    AutoCompleteStringCollection stringCollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection
    {
        "asdfjdkjdfColocar esse texto no TextBoxqewprqewriworuoewi"
    };

    textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = stringCollection;
}
```

Fiz aqui um exemplo para pegar a string pelo meio, usei uma variável `string` chamada *typed* no escopo da classe para guardar o que foi digitado, tem algumas falhas, precisa remover caracteres em caso de delete/backspace, saber o sitio onde remover, selecionar vários caracteres e apagar etc....

```
string typed = "";

private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    string padrao = "asdfjdkjdfColocar esse texto no TextBoxqewprqewriworuoewi";

    e.Handled = true;

    // TODO:: tratamento de delete, backspace, escape etc

    typed += ((char)e.KeyChar).ToString();

    this.textBox1.Text = typed;

    int indexOf = padrao.IndexOf(typed, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    if (indexOf >= 0)
    {
        this.textBox1.Text += padrao.Substring(indexOf + typed.Length);
    }

     this.textBox1.SelectionStart = typed.Length;
     this.textBox1.SelectionLength = this.textBox1.Text.Length - typed.Length;

}
```

Comment: Excelente! estava tentando isso há dias e nada...